# Voltage drop in a Permanent Magnet Generator

Tags: voltage, generator

A small alternator type 4-pole permanent magnet generator(PMG) outputs AC sinusoidal voltage from 1V to 30V where output voltage amplitude increase with frequency.

I first set the generator to rotate with a constant rpm. 
When I hook up the output of the PMG directly to the oscilloscope I can see the true voltage output. So far so good..

My aim is to decrease the voltage output of this PMG by a voltage divider and couple it to a comparator as an input. The reason is, if I don't do that the input to the comparator from the PMG will exceed comparator's rail voltages at high rpm.

So I decided to use a 330k and a 33k resistor to make a voltage divider. I set the generator rpm such that its output was 12V when hooked up to the scope.

Then I coupled the output of the PMG to this voltage divider. I wanted to be sure if I'm doing things in the right way, so I checked the voltage across the voltage divider (across 330+30 = 360k), and what i saw was there was almost no signal in the scope. The voltage output dramatically dropped.

Here is a simple illustration about what I wrote:

[image]

Why does it happen? Should I  use a much higher resistors values for the voltage divider?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5StmM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 and 2. 12 V AC on open circuit. 0 V when loaded with 360k.*

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It's very simple to use. Add in a schematic and a photo of the setup may help too.

Comment: I added some illustration about it. Here is the PMG device: http://www.nei.co.jp/newproducts/fu_ryokuhatudenkimusenfu_sokukei.htm I just know it is a  4 pole PMG and they dont have more data sheet. And this is related to my previous question(Im trying to lower the input voltage to the comparator): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219421/trouble-with-schimtt-trigger-settings-for-varying-sinusoidal-inputs

Comment: There really is a schematic editor button ...! You forgot to mention that your generator was the size of your thumb. Since your scope has an input impedance of 1M (confirm?) your resistors shouldn't load it too much. It sounds as though you have an incorrect value or short. Check again.

Comment: I added an editable schematic for you. Are you sure the PMG is actually connected?

Comment: Yes it was and there was a friend with me we checked several times. Im home right now.

Comment: PMG is not that small, not that tiny. It can output up to 30V. See the link I provided in comments

Comment: I did look. [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nei.co.jp%2Fnewproducts%2Ffu_ryokuhatudenkimusenfu_sokukei.htm&edit-text=). The whole thing is 380 mm high and, I presume the PMG is in the base. It may output 30 V when unloaded but the current could be tiny. The brochure shows a label near the base. Can we have a photo? There may be a Japanese expert around. What's the coil resistance?

Comment: Since scope input impedance can result readings. Mayme I should use some megaohms for divider?

Comment: "NS-30A wind speed transmitter - alternator type... transmits wind speed data in the generated electric power." should have plenty of power to drive a 360k load.

Comment: @transistor I was wrong, it was my mistake. I can actually use a voltage divider. But for this device is that safe to use for examole 40k as shunt resistor fir 12V output? Im afraid to burn its coil resistance if I use a small resistor. Any idea?

Comment: @user16307: I have no idea. You didn't supply the coil resistance when asked.

Answer (score 1):

Since this turns out to be an anemometer - oh, the torture we go through to extract relevant details from the questioners! - and it's probably related to your [Schmitt trigger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219421/trouble-with-schimtt-trigger-settings-for-varying-sinusoidal-inputs/219427?noredirect=1#comment471232_219427) question I suggest you try a different approach. I presume you will feed this into a micro-controller to calculate the wind speed.

If so, you could use an op-amp based precision rectifier to convert the signal to DC and use a potential divider to feed it to the micro ADC. The PMG p-p voltage should have a linear relationship with speed.

Comment: I need frequency otherwise I could measure the rms value.

Comment: it wont go to a uC, it will go to a DAQ. The reason Im trying to lower the input is, it might exceed even 24V to negative input of comparator at 24V Vcc. My last option to increase the rail voltage to 36V, if I cant lower the Vin from the generator with voltage divider. I noticed if input to comparator voltage comes close or exceeds rail Vcc the pulses may produce rant pulses or they become twinlike.

Comment: Just capacitively couple the output to a pulse shaper, and then measure the frequency from the output of that.  Even a one or two CMOS inverters can handle the pulse shaping.  Clip the input signal with some zener diodes if need be.